# Pointer of type Void function handling

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I am using this library of linked lists, but I am having a problem while listing the saved clients, I am only getting the last insert client.
Noting that list_iterator_next() function return a void pointer,
what's the problem in my code ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "simclist.h"   /* use the SimCList library */


int main() {

    // initialize clients
    list_t clients;

    // structure to append
    typedef struct client{
        char ip[45];
        int port;
    } client;

    client client1;

    int i;
    char ip[45];
    int port;

    // initialize the list
    list_init(&clients);

    for( i  = 1 ; i <= 3; i++ ){
        printf("Insert your ip: ");
        scanf("%s", &ip);
        strcpy( client1.ip , ip );

        printf("Insert your port:");
        scanf("%d", &port);
        client1.port = port;

        list_append(&clients, &client1);
    }

    // size of list
    printf("The list now holds %u elements.\n", list_size(&clients));

    // starting iterator session
    list_iterator_start(&clients);
    // check if there is more values
    while (list_iterator_hasnext(&clients)) {
        // get the next value
        client show_client = *(client *)list_iterator_next(&clients); 
        printf("%s:%d\n", show_client.ip, show_client.port);
    }

    list_iterator_stop(&clients);

    list_destroy(&clients);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're only getting the last client stored, then the trouble is (probably) that the list mechanism you're using doesn't make a copy of the data you insert into the list, so each time you overwrite `client1` with a new value, you're also overwriting the value(s) in the list.  You need to create a new client for each value that you read, for example using an array of clients (quick and easy — suggested for testing) or using dynamic allocation (`malloc()` et al).  Long term, you'll probably want to use dynamic allocation, but to prove the point, an array will be easier.

Comment: You should really check the `int` return values from `list_append()` and `list_iterator_start()`.

Comment: what can be an alternative to store for example a username, ip and for for each client in a data structure in a better way than this provided above ? @WeatherVane

Comment: I only made a passing comment - if the functions I mention don't return the correct status you won't get far with iterating the list. Apart from that, I can't see anything wrong. I know it makes the program harder to write, but it makes it easier to find errors too.

Comment: You didn't tell us what value is printed by `printf("The list now holds %u elements.\n", list_size(&clients));` and if it is 3, you didn't tell us if all 3 list elements hold the same data.

Comment: @WeatherVane yes that's right, for example I have 3 clients I insert each ip and port differently, and when I print it out, it shows the same value 3 times, which is last inserted value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already proposed by Jonathan Leffler, you need to dynamically allocate memory for each individual client. SimCList will not do that for you; it cannot and will not take responsibility for your memory management.

Replace this line:

```
list_append(&clients, &client1);
```

by:

```
list_append(&clients, duplicate_client(&client1));
```

The naive implementation of `duplicate_client` is:

```
client *duplicate_client(client *c)
{
    return memcpy(malloc(sizeof(client)), c, sizeof(client));
}
```

but some exception handling is highly recommended (to prevent a segfault in case `malloc` returns NULL).

Disclaimer: I haven't tested this.

Off-topic: please take some time to prevent memory overruns; `scanf` and `strcpy` are not safe.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer, but you can check out @JonathanLeffler comment by using an array such as this. You will then find out if the list library is taking *just* the struct pointer, or the *whole* data struct content.

Note the change in `i` loop, the omission of the `&` before a string identifier in `scanf()`, and using `scanf()` directly on the struct fields. Finally - watch out for the string lengths!

```
client client1[3];
for( i=0 ; i<3; i++ ){
    printf("Insert your ip: ");
    scanf("%44s", client1[i].ip);

    printf("Insert your port:");
    scanf("%d", &client1[i].port);

    if (list_append(&clients, &client1[i]) != 1) {
        printf ("List append failed\n");
        exit (1);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Coming back to this, the answer is now obvious. Since the only thing `int list_append(list_t *restrict l, const void *data)` knows about `struct client` is a `void*` pointer to it, it cannot possibly know the size of the data to copy, and therefore the external data in the list it creates, comprises only the pointers it is given. So @JonathanLeffler is correct: by passing the same `struct` pointer for every insertion, all elements of the list have the same pointer, and so only the most recent data.